# Function to determine how many times an integer can be divided by $2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, divisibility

Is there a function that returns how many times a number can be divided by $2$?

For example:
$$f(7) = 0$$
$$f(38) = 1$$
$$f(48) = 4$$

I assume it would have to be some kind of trigonometric function but I can’t figure it out.

$\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot x\right) + \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \cdot x\right) $ gives $1$ for numbers divisible by two and $2$ for numbers divisible by $4$ but the pattern does not continue.

Any and all help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134811/quick-way-to-find-the-highest-multiplicity-of-a-divisor-of-a-number).

Comment: There is such a _function_ - you have defined it. I think you are asking for a _formula_ using familiar functions. There I think the answer is "no". You can write an _algorithm_ easy to implement on a computer.

Comment: Keep dividing by 2 until you get an odd remainder.  In *Mathematica*:  `Select[FactorInteger[64], First[#] == 2 &][[1, 2]]` and put your n into the position where 64 is.

Comment: Since you aren't specific about what a "number" is, you can convert it to binary if not already in that form and count the zeros to the right.

Comment: You might find it interesting to know how much a thing called [$p$-adic valuation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation) (for any prime $p$) is studied in modern number theory. Yours is the $2$-adic valuation.

Comment: If you are only interested in computing it, note that in the particular case of binary such functions are often already implemented on processors, it is the "**trailing zero count**" or TZCNT instruction and there also exists bit hacks for that (cf. http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The polynomial $f_n(z)=1+z+...+z^{n-1}$ has all $n^{th}$ roots of unity as roots, excluding $1$, so we find that $g_n(x)=f_n(e^{2\pi i x/n})$ is $n$ at any integer multiple of $n$, and zero at all other integers. The real part of this function can be written as

$$\Re (g_n(x))=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \cos(2\pi mx/n)$$

The desired counting function $\nu_2(x)$ is a sum

$$\nu_2(x)=\Re\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_{2^n}(x)/2^n\right)$$

Since each term is one precisely for each $n$ for which $2^n$ divides $x$. So,

$$\nu_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^{2^n-1} \cos(2\pi mx/2^n)/2^n$$

is the function.

Comments have focused on the question of how, given an integer $n$ to compute the largest power of $2$ dividing $n$. My answer is not a good way to do this. It is, I think more in the spirit of the OP's post, however.